# My code stop when first match and I need to search whole text

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops, search

Looks like problem here but I could not find out how to continue search after first match. I need to make a program of Horspool Algorithm a I'm stuck in there. It is supposed to search all text but when matches for first time it stops.

```
public static class BoyerMooreHorspool
{


    public static int Find(string haystack, string needle)
    {
        // If substring is bigger than string, no match exists
        if (needle.Length > haystack.Length)
            return -1;

        // If the substring has characters not in the string, no match exists
        if (needle.Except(haystack).Any())
            return -1;

        Dictionary<char, int> BadMatchTable = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        // Initializes every letter with the default value
        foreach (char c in haystack)
        {
            if (!BadMatchTable.Keys.Contains(c))
                BadMatchTable.Add(c, needle.Length);
        }

        // The formula for every letter in the needle (except the last) is lenght - index - 1
        for (int i = 0; i < needle.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            BadMatchTable[needle[i]] = needle.Length - i - 1;
        }

        int index = 0;

        while (index <= haystack.Length - needle.Length)
        {
            bool match = true;
            for (int i = needle.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (needle[i] != haystack[index + i])
                {
                    match = false;
                    index = index + BadMatchTable[haystack[index + needle.Length - 1]];
                }

            }
            if (match)
            {
                return index;
            }
            if (index==haystack.Length)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
        }
}
```

Comment: It's doing this because you're returning a value on the first match. `return index;` will stop the execution of the loop, and return value to the `Find` method caller.

Comment: Can you gives us any clues on what return value you are expecting?

Comment: yes but when i try to change this it goes endless loop

Comment: @Stefan i need to find all matches in haystack, total compare number and total match number

Comment: first i tried define a list and add match index to this list but i didn't work out

Comment: Have your tried debugging yet? What were your findings?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
return index;
```

try

```
yield return index;
```

Comment: thanks but i've got this error message : CS1622 Can not return value from an iterator. Use the yield return statement to return the value or the yield break statement to terminate the iteration.  AND ALSO THIS ERROR CS1624 'BoyerMooreHorspool.Find (string, string)' can not be an iterator block because 'int' is not a type of iterator interface